# Testing connection to MySQL with Python using subprocess

Tags: python, mysql, bash, subprocess

I am trying to test a connection to MySQL in my Python script using subprocess and a Bash command. I want to make sure the password provided by the user is correct before trying to connect and send more MySQL commands. I am aware I can do it easily by importing MySQLdb, but I'd like to learn how to make this work.

This is what I have:

```
root_password = getpass.getpass("Enter the password of the database root user: ")
try:
   subprocess.check_call("mysql -u root -p%s" % root_password, shell=True, stdout=open('/dev/null', 'w'), stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
except:
   print "Incorrect password provided."
```

When the password is correct, stdin hangs waiting for further prompts, but I want it to exit back out so that I can issue this:

```
mysql_cmd = 'mysql -u root -p{0} -Bse "CREATE DATABASE {1}; CREATE USER {2}@localhost IDENTIFIED BY \'{3}\'; GRANT SELECT, CREATE, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, ALTER, DROP, LOCK TABLES ON {1}.* TO {2}@localhost IDENTIFIED BY \'{3}\'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"'.format(root_password, database_name, database_user, database_password)
subprocess.call(mysql_cmd, shell=True, stdout=open('/dev/null', 'w'), stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Yea, you guessed it; I am trying to convert a Bash script into Python.

Comment: Likely, you have to escape your password correctly, if you want to pass it through command line. And, in general, it's a very, very bad idea, because every user in your system may observe your command with password in the process list

Comment: Escaping the password isn't the problem since the command goes through successfully and returns a mysql prompt. I want to just test if the password is correct and not return a mysql prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Connecting to MySQL Using Connector/Python](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-connecting.html):

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode

try:
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password=password, 
                                   database='test') # MySQL 4.1+
except mysql.connector.Error as err:
    if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
        print("Something is wrong with your user name or password")
    elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
        print("Database does not exists")
    else:
        print(err)
else:
    conn.close()
```

---

If `mysql` command displays a prompt when the password is correct then you could use `Popen.communicate()` to send `exit` command:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, DEVNULL, STDOUT

p = Popen(["mysql", "-u", "root", "-p", password],
          stdin=PIPE, stdout=DEVNULL, stderr=STDOUT)
p.communicate(b"exit")
if p.returncode != 0:
    print('incorrect password')
```

Keep in mind the security implications mentioned in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22826243/testing-connection-to-mysql-with-python-using-subprocess#comment34816877_22826243).

Comment: Awesome. That's what I was looking for.